# cloning does the same thing as parents clone

Tags: jquery, clone

I have code like this, when I choose list from select box before I click button clone it's show data, so after that I click button clone, why it's direct appear the data on the clone? What I want is  when I choose list from select box clone, the cloning don't direct appear the data before I choose list from select box cloning.

And the other problems it's the cloning affect to the other her parents or other cloning. How to clone technique without affect to the other clone?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on( "click", "a#addhewan", function() {
   var confirm = window.confirm('Yakin menambah data hewan??');            
   if(confirm == true){                
    var newForm = $('.form1 .data_hewan').html();            
    $(newForm).insertBefore('.newForm');
             // $('.master-hewan').addClass('hidden');        
         }
     });

  $(document).on("change","#pet_name",function(){
   var allRule = $('.all-rule');
   if($(this).val() == 1){
    var form1 = $('.form1').find('.all-rule .formRule1').clone().removeClass('hidden');
    $(form1).appendTo('.show-rule');
   }
  })
 });
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>fdsjf</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form1">
  <div class="data_hewan">
   <select name="pet" class="form-control" id="pet_name">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Pilih Ras Hewan</option>
    <option value="1">Korean Jindo</option>
    <option value="2">Siberian Husky</option>
    <option value="3">Maine Coon</option>
   </select>

   <div class="all-rule hidden">
    <div class="formRule1 hidden">
     <span>halo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="formRule2 hidden">
     <span>eooo</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="show-rule">
   </div>
   <div class="newForm">

   </div>
  </div>
  <a id="addhewan" name="add" id="addhewan">Add Hewan</a>
 </div>

 
</body>
</html>
```

What I want:

[image]

Comment: `$('.form1').find('.all-rule').each(".formRule").clone().removeClass('hidden').find("span").text("")` or whatever you are trying to clear and you may have to toy with the clone function

Comment: @yardpenalty i don't wanna to clear, but what i want is the cloning don't affect to the other clone or her parents, the code that i gave i think it's wrong. When i clone   and i chose 'korean jindo' it affect to the other. How to clone without affect to the other,
thanks for responing

Comment: so the new cloning it's fresh for doing action for it self

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly,  you have to first capture the clone and point to it with a variable name. Then remove the hidden class and clear the text in span. Something like `var field = $('.form1').find('.all-rule .formRule1')clone(); field.removeClass("hidden").find("span").text(""); $(field).appendTo('.show-rule');` I suggest using id for form for clarity.

Comment: try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yardpenalty/n7bagx9d/31/)

Comment: it's not work, still affect to the other clone

Comment: well if you are asking to do the same thing to every clone you will get same results. I am not understanding the goal. I have looked at image too

Comment: the goal is when you choose the list select box from resutl clone example korean jindo it's show data for select box first before clone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to fix the html and jQuery selector `$('.form1').find('.all-rule .formRule1')` will apply to all .formRule1 so you need to specify the parent. check this code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on( "click", "a#addhewan", function() {
   var confirm = window.confirm('Yakin menambah data hewan??');            
   if(confirm == true){                
       var newForm = $('.form1 .data_hewan:first').clone();            
                newForm.find('.show-rule').html('');
    newForm.insertBefore('.newForm');
             // $('.master-hewan').addClass('hidden');        
         }
     });

  $(document).on("change","#pet_name",function(){
   var data = $(this).parent();
   if($(this).val() == 1){
    var form1 = data.find('.all-rule .formRule1').clone().removeClass('hidden');
    form1.appendTo(data.find('.show-rule'));
   }
  })
 });
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>fdsjf</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="form1">
  <div class="data_hewan">
   <select name="pet" class="form-control" id="pet_name">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Pilih Ras Hewan</option>
    <option value="1">Korean Jindo</option>
    <option value="2">Siberian Husky</option>
    <option value="3">Maine Coon</option>
   </select>

   <div class="all-rule hidden">
    <div class="formRule1 hidden">
     <span>halo</span>
    </div>
    <div class="formRule2 hidden">
     <span>eooo</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="show-rule">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="newForm"></div>
  <a id="addhewan" name="add" id="addhewan">Add Hewan</a>
 </div>

 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can i ask again ? @atmahadli

Comment: @ronies you're welcome. I'm not open SO everyday but you can ask anytime here in SO.